# Why is my Python script not using the virtualenv set for it?

Tags: python, virtualenv

So I don't use virtual env often. In this particular case I need to have a desktop app for a client where they can input a CSV and then I use pandas to modify columns and such and return it to them. For the desktop app I'm using electron, and I already have been able to send and return data between the two processes it's using. To work on this I've been using this tutorial:
https://efficientcoder.net/connect-python-3-electron-nodejs-build-desktop-apps/

So I set up my virtualenv but when I ran the process it said that any module I had installed in the virtualenv was unable to be found. I ran a check and it's using the python from my system not the env from the parent directory. How can I fix this?

`calc.py`

```
import sys
print(sys.path)

>>> Outputs: ['C:\\Users\\*Me*\\Projects\\electron-poc\\py', 'C:\\Python310\\python310.zip', 'C:\\Python310\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python310\\lib', 'C:\\Python310', 'C:\\Python310\\lib\\site-packages']
```

Comment: How did you setup your venv and how did you activated it ?

Comment: @David I have a directory of files all of which are contained in a folder called electron-poc. I ran the command py -m venv env to create an "env" folder in my directory. Then I activated it with the activate.bat file, then I installed my modules and they showed up where they were supposed to

Comment: Do you have many version of python installed ?

Comment: @David Just one other than in the virtual env